# Total with select query

Tags: sql

Consider the following data:

```
Insurance_Comp | 1To30DaysAgeing | 31To60DaysAgeing | 61To90DaysAgeing | TotalVehicles

=============================================================================

ABC | 30 | 5 | 20 | 55

XYZ | 10 | 35 | 5 | 50
```

I am calculating the number of vehicles aged for particular group after a stock# is assigned to that vehicle. The number of vehicles for a group (ex. 1 to 30 Days Ageing) is calculated using a complex query. I have written SP to get this result. What I want is to calculate the total of vehicles while executing the same select query. For simplification I have created functions in SQL to get number of vehicles for each group.

Right now I m using the query like this  ...

```
Select Ins_Comp, dbo.fn_1To30Ageing(...), dbo.fn_31To60Ageing(...), dbo.fn_61To90Ageing(...) from Table Where ....
```

I am calculating the total using RowDataBound event of GridView in ASP.NET with C#. Is there any way to calculate the total within query itself?  By the way I don't want total as dbo.fn_1To30Ageing(...)+ dbo.fn_31To60Ageing(...) + dbo.fn_61To90Ageing, because that requires double processing time.

Comment: Could you post the output data that you would like to see? what does fn_1to30..., fn_31to60... do?

Comment: The output I wanted is on top. The functions calculates the days aged. dbo.fn_1To30Ageing() function calculates the number of days aged between 1 to 30. I want to calculate the last column TotalVehicles within query itself.

Comment: It will be easier to understand, if you put the input data and output data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familir with ASP.NET, but if it is only SQL aspect, you can certainly use sub-query:

SELECT A,B,C,SUM(A+B+C) FROM  (
  Select Ins_Comp, dbo.fn_1To30Ageing(...) AS A, dbo.fn_31To60Ageing(...) AS B, dbo.fn_61To90Ageing(...) AS C from Table Where ....
  ) TEMP

Comment: I think you have not read my question completely. The values of A,B,C are calculated through functions and I dont want total again by calling them.

Comment: Hey, easy there, your question is confusing due to lack of info. The above query only uses each function once, where is the problem?

Comment: Yes, the sub-query one only execute those 3 functions once, not twice.

Comment: I need to nest select while i was trying single select.